# Combine multiple form validate independently in flask-wtf and commit to db

Tags: ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've created a questionnaire in which, each user visit '/{questionnaire_id}/{question_number}' to answer to them. To do so, when the user start the questionnaire, the app redirect the user to '/{questionnaire_id}/{question_0}' and when he submit the answer page will redirect to '/{questionnaire_id}/{question_1}' and so on.

I've created a field in my answer_db named 'completed' and it's default is 0. When the user answer to all questions the app will change the 'completed' field to 1 which implies that these answer could be added to analysis part.

It's work properly but it's not efficient. I want to use Ajax in a way that solve 2 problem for me.

1. Show all the questions in a same url to avoid redirection
2. Submit all the answers to db when all the questions answered which helps me to remove 'completed' field

I was wondering if it is possible or not

Comment: Yeah it's possible.